# tikz error: illegal unit of measure and missing number

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, subfloats

I have 3 sub bar plots which placed vertically in line. But the 3rd one doesn´t show totally due to space limitation. Mico suggested me to use figure and subfigure environment. I have changed table subtable to figure subfigure. Now  the problem is with \textwidth. I have already given a number to it, but TexMaker still tell me missing number, and it´s illegal unit of measure..

> error msg: ! Missing number, treated as zero.  }
>   l.16 \begin{subfigure}{0.9\textwidth} A number should have been here;
>   I inserted `0'. (If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
>   look up`weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.) ! Illegal unit of
>   measure (pt inserted).

My script is under, here I present only one bar plot in order to shorten the script :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{bblue}{HTML}{4F81BD}
\definecolor{rred}{HTML}{C0504D}
\definecolor{ggreen}{HTML}{9BBB59}
\definecolor{ppurple}{HTML}{9F4C7C}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{1\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 1*\textwidth,
        height = 8cm,
        enlarge y limits={upper, value=0.2},
        ymin=0,
        major x tick style = transparent,
        ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
        bar width=20pt,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        ylabel = {Percentage Error in X Direction \%},
        symbolic x coords={FH,UT,LT},
        xtick = data,
        nodes near coords,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        enlarge x limits=0.25,
        ymin=0,
        legend cell align=left,
        legend style={
                at={(1,1.05)},
                anchor=south east,
                column sep=1ex
        }
    ]
        \addplot[style={bblue,fill=bblue,mark=none]}]
            coordinates {(FH, 100) (UT,100) (LT,100)};

        \addplot[style={rred,fill=rred,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(FH, 89) (UT,170) (LT,173)};
        \legend{M,V}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{In longitudinal Direction}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I indeed recommended you use `figure` and `subfigure` environments. Just for the record: I did *not* recommend that you load the `subfigure` package...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't load the `subfigure` package -- it's deprecated. Instead, load the `subcaption` package. It's the same package as you loaded in your earlier query, which was about `subtable` environments.

Since the bar charts are sufficiently large so that all three can't fit on a page, I suggest you use the `\ContinuedFloat` macro (provided by the `caption` package). Place the first two `subfigure` environments in a `figure` on one page, and place one more `subfigure`, along with a `\ContinuedFloat` directive, in a second `figure` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
%%\usepackage{subfigure} % Don't load this package -- it's deprecated!
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption} % <-- load the "subcaption" package instead
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{bblue}{HTML}{4F81BD}
\definecolor{rred}{HTML}{C0504D}
\definecolor{ggreen}{HTML}{9BBB59}
\definecolor{ppurple}{HTML}{9F4C7C}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p] % start of the first "figure" environment
\caption{Three bar charts}
\begin{subfigure}{1\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 1*\textwidth,
        height = 8cm,
        enlarge y limits={upper, value=0.2},
        ymin=0,
        major x tick style = transparent,
        ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
        bar width=20pt,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        ylabel = {Percentage Error in X Direction \%},
        symbolic x coords={FH,UT,LT},
        xtick = data,
        nodes near coords,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        enlarge x limits=0.25,
        ymin=0,
        legend cell align=left,
        legend style={
                at={(1,1.05)},
                anchor=south east,
                column sep=1ex
        }
    ]
        \addplot[style={bblue,fill=bblue,mark=none]}]
            coordinates {(FH, 100) (UT,100) (LT,100)};

        \addplot[style={rred,fill=rred,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(FH, 89) (UT,170) (LT,173)};
        \legend{M,V}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{First}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{1\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 1*\textwidth,
        height = 8cm,
        enlarge y limits={upper, value=0.2},
        ymin=0,
        major x tick style = transparent,
        ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
        bar width=20pt,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        ylabel = {Percentage Error in X Direction \%},
        symbolic x coords={FH,UT,LT},
        xtick = data,
        nodes near coords,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        enlarge x limits=0.25,
        ymin=0,
        legend cell align=left,
        legend style={
                at={(1,1.05)},
                anchor=south east,
                column sep=1ex
        }
    ]
        \addplot[style={bblue,fill=bblue,mark=none]}]
            coordinates {(FH, 100) (UT,100) (LT,100)};

        \addplot[style={rred,fill=rred,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(FH, 89) (UT,170) (LT,173)};
        \legend{M,V}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Second}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure} % End of the first "figure" environment

\begin{figure}[t!] % Start of the second "figure" environment
\ContinuedFloat % to ensure that the next subfigure is labelled "(c)", not "(a)"
\begin{subfigure}{1\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 1*\textwidth,
        height = 8cm,
        enlarge y limits={upper, value=0.2},
        ymin=0,
        major x tick style = transparent,
        ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
        bar width=20pt,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        ylabel = {Percentage Error in X Direction \%},
        symbolic x coords={FH,UT,LT},
        xtick = data,
        nodes near coords,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        enlarge x limits=0.25,
        ymin=0,
        legend cell align=left,
        legend style={
                at={(1,1.05)},
                anchor=south east,
                column sep=1ex
        }
    ]
        \addplot[style={bblue,fill=bblue,mark=none]}]
            coordinates {(FH, 100) (UT,100) (LT,100)};

        \addplot[style={rred,fill=rred,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(FH, 89) (UT,170) (LT,173)};
        \legend{M,V}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Third}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure} % End of the second "figure" environment

\end{document}
```